# Focus on first item of first LongListSelector within a Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a report to fill in that is made up of a `List` of sections, each of which has a `List` of questions. My current implementation uses a `Pivot` control whose `ItemsSource` is set to the `List` of sections and `DataTemplate` is a `LongListSelector` whose `ItemsSource` is set to the `List` of questions.

When the user attempts to submit the report, I loop through all the questions to check their validity. If any come back invalid, a flag is set and an error message is shown next to that question.

I would like to be able to focus on the first question that has that flag set but cannot figure out how to obtain a reference to the required `LongListSelector` so that I can call it's `ScrollTo` method.

Code:

**View**

```
<phone:Pivot toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="0"
                 Name="QuestionPivot"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Sections, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <phone:Pivot.Title>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                <Run Text=" "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.DailyReport, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
                <Run Text=" - "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ProjectName}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </phone:Pivot.Title>            
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SectionName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Questions, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 20">
                                ...  
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>

    </phone:Pivot>
```

**Code Behind** (including my failed attempt to cast the SelectedItem to a LongListSelector...)

```
    private void FocusOnFirstInvalid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedItem = 1;
        foreach (ReportDraftSection s in QuestionPivot.Items)
        {
            foreach(ReportQuestion q in s.Questions)
            {
                if(q.IsNotValid)
                {
                    QuestionPivot.SelectedIndex = selectedItem;
                    var l = (LongListSelector)QuestionPivot.SelectedItem;
                    l.ScrollTo(q);
                }
            }
            selectedItem += 1;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Pivot's `ItemsSource` is a List of `Section`, `QuestionPivot.SelectedItem` contains a `Section` object instead of LongListSelector. You can try to use `ItemContainerGenerator` to get PivotItem from `SelectedItem`, then get LongListSelector from PivotItem's `Content` (not tested yet) :

```
.......
QuestionPivot.SelectedIndex = selectedItem;
var pivotItem = (PivotItem)QuestionPivot
                .ItemContainerGenerator
                .ContainerFromItem(QuestionPivot.SelectedItem);
var l = (LongListSelector)pivotItem.Content;
l.ScrollTo(q);
.......
```

Comment: Sadly `ContainerFromItem` returns the `Section` and exploring the `PivotItem` itself hasn't borne fruit. Currently having a look at the `VisualTreeHelper`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I used the `PivotItem` from your suggestion, then the used the `VisualTreeHelper` to drill down to the `LongListSelector`.